# How different installs of the same version of Internet Explorer 7 produce different render results

Tags: internet-explorer-7

Situation: Client is a government organization who is using Internet Explorer v7.0.5730.13. On the developer side there is same version of Internet Explorer and the same OS. Client cannot install any other browser or change any settings in IE.

Question: What other variables are there which could influence this kind of odd render behavior?

[image: Expected Render]
[image: Actual Render]

Comment: You have to give a more concrete description, perhaps with screenshots, or at the very least, the elements in question.

Comment: Generally elements are misaligned, some are behind others, width of some elements is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible one of the CSS files not loading up on one browser Check with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or simply look at the IIS logs.

One alternative is to disable one CSS file at a time and see if you can get the page to render incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Is the resolution and zoom level the same one each? Are both windows maximized? Is the same user logged into both computers and both web apps?

Comment: zoom is the same (100%), windows are maximized. User is using one app at a time